# Не проходит POST запрос к функции mvc-контроллера, отправляемый JS функцией - ошибка 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Необходимо обновить тело tbody таблицы не перезагружая страницу. Страница формируется mvc-контроллером. Для этого в mvc-контроллере, который формирует данную страницу прописал нужный метод, который принимает POST-запросы - GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public class PollingStationsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly VoterCollectorContext _context;

        public PollingStationsController(VoterCollectorContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        // GET: PollingStations
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var voterCollectorContext = _context.PollingStation.Include(s => s.Station).Include(p => p.City).Include(p => p.House).Include(p => p.MicroDistrict).Include(p => p.Street);
            return View(await voterCollectorContext.ToListAsync());
        }
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict([FromBody] ElectoralDistrictDTO electoralDistrictDTO)
        {
            List<District> districts = _context.District.Where(d => d.ElectoralDistrictId == electoralDistrictDTO.IdElectoralDistrict).ToList();
            List<int> selectStationsId = districts.Select(d => d.StationId ?? 0).ToList();

            List<PollingStation> pollingStations = _context.PollingStation.Include(p => p.City).Include(p => p.Street).Include(p => p.House)
                .Where(p => selectStationsId.Contains(p.StationId ?? 0)).ToList();

            return PartialView(pollingStations);
        }
}
```

Подключил файл `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/JS_Index_PollingStations.js"></script>` , написал в нем JS функцию, которая формирует и отправляет ajax-запрос на сервер:

```
$(function () {
    $("#SelectElectoralDistrictId").change(function () {
        var formData = {'IdElectoralDistrict': Number.parseInt($('#SelectElectoralDistrictId').val()), 'Name': $('#SelectElectoralDistrictId>option:selected').text() };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict")/',
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'RequestVerificationToken': $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function (data) {

                $('#tableBodyPollingStation').replaceWith(data);

            },
            error: function (result, status, er) {
                alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
            }
        });
    });
```

Но запрос до метода не доходит - выдает 404, и в ней странно отображает путь:

> POST http://localhost:18246/@Url.Action(%22GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict%22) 404 (Not Found)

Для обновления tbody таблицы данными с сервера создал представление:

```
@model IEnumerable<voteCollector.Models.PollingStation>;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict";
}

<tbody id="tableBodyPollingStation">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Station.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Street.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.House.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.IdPollingStation">Править</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.IdPollingStation">Удалить</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Зачем вам @Url.Action? Очевидно оно не сработало. Попробуйте просто `url: '/GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict/'`. Но я могу ошибаться, так как с Blazor не дружу.

Comment: @aepot, да, если указать ```url: 'PollingStations/GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict/'```, то запрос проходит, где-то я увидел, что запросы к mvc-контроллерам делаются через @Url.Action. Теперь при возврате объектов на фронт и попытке заполнения созданного представления выдает ошибку - error: [object Object] status: parsererror er:SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2.  Он попадает в for, созданного частичного представления, но уже на 2-м объекте выдает такую ошибку. Но это уже получается другая история и другой вопрос )

Comment: И лучше сперва отладить через postman, что бы разделить проблемы фронта и бека